# Get the value of a Pair of Ints(Key Value) on a HashTable

Tags: java, hashtable

I did a HashTable like this:

```
Hashtable<Integer, Pair> resul = new Hashtable<Integer, Pair>();

int largo, row, col;
```

When "Pair" is my class to store 2 Ints and it looks like this:

```
public class Pair<T, U> {

    public final T t;
    public final U u;

    public Pair(T t, U u) {
        this.t = t;
        this.u = u;
    }
}
```

So I added elements on my HasTable:

`resul.put(largo, new Pair(row, col + 1));`

Now I need my Pair of numbers(ints) so I can display them, how do I get those Pairs numbers?

I want something like:

```
if (resul.containsKey(0)) {
   //Print my "Pair" numbers here
   //or better: Print my first number here
   //Print my second number here
}
```

Comment: There's a phrase that goes something like "always program to an interface." The interface for Hashtable is Dictionary, so you should declare and initialize your Hashtable as follows: `Dictionary<Integer, Pair> resul = new Hashtable<>();`

Comment: @ThisClark I'm new on Java, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access you object inside Hashtable just calling it by key value

```
public synchronized V get(Object key);
```

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hashtable<Integer, Pair> result = new Hashtable<Integer, Pair>();

    result.put(1, new Pair(1, 1 + 1));

    if (result.containsKey(1)) {
        Pair pair = result.get(1);
        System.out.println(pair.t);
        System.out.println(pair.u);
    }
}
```

The better approach is to keep you instance variables private inside the class, and use getters:

```
class Pair<T, U> {

    private final T t;
    private final U u;

    public Pair(T t, U u) {
        this.t = t;
        this.u = u;
    }

    public T getT() {
        return t;
    }

    public U getU() {
        return u;
    }
}
```

Therefore:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Hashtable<Integer, Pair> result = new Hashtable<Integer, Pair>();

    result.put(1, new Pair(1, 1 + 1));

    if (result.containsKey(1)) {
        Pair pair = result.get(1);
        System.out.println(pair.getT());
        System.out.println(pair.getU());
    }
}
```